# Server socket in python doesn't print new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying simple client and sinple server , client send 2 massages and server recieve 2 massages . I am printg first massage print(data1) and second massage print(data2) and somehow it print both massages in the same line . Can you help ?

## server

```
import socket

SERVER_IP = '0.0.0.0'
DEST_PORT = 1731

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP,DEST_PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)
client_socket,address=server_socket.accept()


data1 = client_socket.recv(512).decode()
print(data1)
data2 = client_socket.recv(512).decode()
print(data2)

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

## cliend code

```
#client
import socket

HOST_IP = '127.0.0.1'
DEST_PORT = 1731

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

my_socket.connect((HOST_IP,DEST_PORT))

data1 = "test1"
print("client send")
my_socket.sendall(data1.encode())
my_socket.sendall("second send ".encode())

my_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets are a stream-oriented protocol, not a message-oriented one.

What's happening is that your client ends up sending `b"test1second send "` before your server reads anything from the socket.

When it does, it reads up to 512 characters – more than enough to contain your message – and again, up to 512 characters yet there are zero to read at that point and an empty line gets printed.

Depending on your actual requirements, you will need to figure out a way to delimit or encapsulate your messages; for text, a popular choice is by newline characters (though it will land you in some hot water should you need to transmit an actual newline in a message).

A better choice still is something like [netstrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring), where each message is preceded by its length (in ASCII for netstrings, but it could be a binary unsigned integer (4 bytes), or whatever you specify), or some sort of [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) scheme.

Comment: Just want to add to this - `data.decode('utf-8').split('\r\n\r\n', 1)[1])` should do the trick?

Comment: @Joel So long as your read call happens to read all of the data! There's no guarantee that you've read an entire delimited/encapsulated message within a single `.read()` call either.

Comment: Sure, but, in this instance, to solve his POC, shouldn't that be the answer? It's not suitable for real-world applications, but for this little program, i think he'd be just fine.

Comment: Maybe – until he's all of a sudden not. :)

Comment: I get that it's not perfect for all situations, but in this instance, I think it'll work just fine for him. You are right in your answer however, but I still think providing an actual (even tho its flawed) solution (maybe add my suggestion to the answer) is better than providing no solution :)

Comment: That said though, OP doesn't actually even _transmit_ newline characters right now :)

Comment: Not from what we can see in this little example :)

Comment: @Joel It's not perfect for any situation. It will probably work for the POC. One day it suddenly won't work and Dan will have to rewrite everything  from scratch to fix it.

Comment: @user253751 I never argued that its perfect, I mean, its conceptually flawed from the start.